# Watches not working in vscode? (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nodemon, npm-start, vscode-debugger

It took me a while to get the debugger to work within Visual Studio Code. Now the program breaks on set breakpoints inside of .vue files/components. But none of the watches seem to work. They are either undefined or unavailable, even when the variables have been created.

The settings I use in `launch.json` :

```
{   
    "name": "chrome debug",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 3000,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/admin",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "breakOnLoad": true
    // "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    //     "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
    // }
}
```

I build my app through `npm run build` or `npm run devbuild` which, by my knowlegde, 'compiles' the .vue components into Javascript files. And then start the app with either `npm start` or `nodemon index.js`.

Package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    <...>
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    "devbuild": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --hide-modules",
    <...>
  },
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried add a new script with nodemon? Something like this:

> "newScript": "nodemon  -L -e ts,json --watch . --exec \"npm run build
>   || npm run devbuild\""

**-L** = Though this should be a last resort as it will poll every file it can find.
**-e** = By default, nodemon looks for files with the .js, .mjs, .coffee, .litcoffee, and .json extensions. If you use the --exec option and monitor app.py nodemon will monitor files with the extension of .py. However, you can specify your own list with the -e (or --ext) switch like so: nodemon -e js,jade
**--watch .** = To watch all the changes on the path, in this case all the code on the current path.
(I got all of this information from the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon).

then, run the command:

> npm run newScript